# Can nifi-app.log file be deleted without having issues sith Nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

'Nifi-app.log' file is taking up too much disk space.
It is not responding to configured limits inside logback.xml and it keeps growing.
There will be any problem if I just simply delete this file 'Nifi-app.log'?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you share your logback.xml configuration? If NiFi is running I wouldn't recommend deleting it because NiFi will be writing it at the same time, but if NiFi is not running you can delete it and will be regenerated the next time you start it.